# Elements' sizes don't update on application loading in Kivy

Tags: python, events, size, kivy, python-3.4

I have `on_size()` event, it works when I resize window, but I can't make it work on application loading correctly (it works, but not like it must):

```
from random import random, randint

import kivy

kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 640)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 480)
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'top', 40)
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 40)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.layout import Layout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Rectangle


class Main(BoxLayout):
    side_padding = 20

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (0, 0)  # Doesn't help.
        self.on_size()  # Doesn't help.

    def on_size(self, *args):
        left, middle, right = self.ids.left, self.ids.middle, self.ids.right
        left.width = max([x.texture_size[0] for x in left.children]) + self.side_padding
        right.width = max([x.texture_size[0] for x in right.children]) + self.side_padding
        available_space = self.width - left.width - right.width
        if available_space > self.height:
            middle.size = (self.height, self.height)
            extra = (self.width - self.height - left.width - right.width) // 2
            left.width += extra
            right.width += extra
        else:
            middle.size = (available_space, available_space)


class SidePanel(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SidePanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class GameField(Layout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.array_size = randint(4, 8)
        self.bind(pos=self.update, size=self.update)
        self.update()

    def update(self, *args):
        s_padding = 1 / 16
        s_sq_size = 1 - 2 * s_padding
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            block_size = self.width / self.array_size
            sq_size = block_size * s_sq_size
            padding = block_size * s_padding
            Color(1, 1, 1)
            for j in range(self.array_size):
                for i in range(self.array_size):
                    Rectangle(pos=(self.x + padding + i * block_size, self.y + padding + j * block_size),
                              size=(sq_size, sq_size))
            for i in range(self.array_size + 1):
                shift = self.width * i / self.array_size
                Line(points=(self.x, self.y + shift, self.x + self.width, self.y + shift))
                Line(points=(self.x + shift, self.y, self.x + shift, self.y + self.height))


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        self.array_size = randint(4, 8)
        self.update()


class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().run()
```

*.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<Main>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, .9
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    SidePanel:
        id: left
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            text: 'Score'
        Label:
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            text: 'Event log log log loooooooooog'
        Label:
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            text: 'Event log log log\n123'
        Label:
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            text: '35mdbj65 qewr'
        Label:
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            text: '3qht6ju7ustju'
    GameField:
        id: middle
    SidePanel:
        id: right
        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            text: 'Menu'
        Label:
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            text: 'Bonuses bonuses'
<SidePanel>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_x: None
    size: self.size

<GameField>:
    pos_hint: {'center_y': .5}
    size_hint: None, None
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .9, .9, .9
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Maybe there is some mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I update my class's children's sizes depending on labels and buttons inside of it, I've added to them `on_size` event:

```
def on_size(self, *args):
    self.parent.parent.on_size()


class SideLabel(Label):
    on_size = on_size


class SideButton(Button):
    on_size = on_size
```

And also I have replaced Buttons and Labels on these classes in kv. It seems to work correctly now.