# Is there some event when all Widgets are presented in Kivy?

Tags: python, widget, kivy, python-3.4

I have 3 Layouts, size of 2nd is depending on widths of children of 2 another Layouts:

```
def on_size(self, *args):
    self.left_panel.width = max(child.texture_size[0] for child in self.left_panel.children) + self.side_padding
    self.right_panel.width = max(child.texture_size[0] for child in self.right_panel.children) + self.side_padding
    available_space = self.width - self.left_panel.width - self.right_panel.width
    if available_space > self.height:
        self.middle_panel.size = (self.height, self.height)
        extra = (self.width - self.height - self.left_panel.width - self.right_panel.width) // 2
        self.left_panel.width += extra
        self.right_panel.width += extra
    else:
        self.middle_panel.size = (available_space, available_space)
    self.middle_panel.calculate_points()
    self.middle_panel.clear_widgets()
    self.middle_panel.redraw_blocks()
```

It works correctly only in 50% cases (randomly) for some reason. If it loads worng, it becomes correct after I resize window. Also for now I call it when `on_size()` of each child of 2 another Layouts triggers, this is bad idea. Is there some event or else when everything is loaded/presented?

**UPDATE:**

This is how it should be (and sometimes it is).
[image]

But sometimes randomly next issue happens (see buttons on the right):
[image]

**UPDATE:**

For now I call it by:

```
class SideButton(Button):
    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.parent.parent.on_size()
```

I know this isn't good idea, because it triggers smth like 30-50 times, but I can't invent smth better.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up `width` and `height`. But if you are putting these layouts in a `BoxLayout`, and set `left_panel` and `right_panel`'s `size_hint_x` to None, then the middle should automatically fill the extra space.

Comment: @RyanP After `size_hint_x: None` Label's text goes over the edge. I have [this (see pictures)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803773/how-do-i-set-minimum-allowable-width-height-for-widget-layout-in-kivy). Also even if it loads wrong, it becomes correct after I resize window.

Comment: @RyanP Sorry, I've forgotten that `size_hint_x` is already None. But it doesn't matter.